# How to assign value from jQuery method to hidden field in Spring mvc form tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I need to pass browser timezone back to my controller and I'm doing this by using a hidden form field in my jsp. I set the value using jQuery val method. However, the value retrieved at the Controller is "". Can you please help.

JSP - Spring form tag:
`

```
<div data-role="content" style="text-align: center">
        <form:form id="user" modelAttribute="user" action="index">
            <form:input path="accountNumber" id="account-number" 
                placeholder="Account Number"/>
            <form:hidden path="timeZone" id="timeZone"  value=""/>
        </form:form>
</div>
```

`

jQuery method:
`$(document).ready(function() {
    var zone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
    $("#timeZone").val(zone);
});`

Comment: Your jQuery code works, you need to check something else than only jquery and HTML markup.

Comment: @Ele You are probably right. Looks like my document.ready function is not called the first time i reach this page. I'll close this question and open a new one